# How to replace strings in text with id from second text?

Tags: awk

I've got two CSV files. The first file contains organism family names and connection weight information but I need to change the format of the file to load it into different programs like Gephi. I have created a second file where each family has an ID value. I haven't found a good example on this site on how to change the family names in the first file to the ids from the second file. Example of my files:

```
$ cat edge_file.csv
Source,Target,Weight,Type,From,To
Argasidae,Alcaligenaceae,0.040968439,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Alcaligenaceae
Argasidae,Burkholderiaceae,0.796351574,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Burkholderiaceae
Argasidae,Methylophilaceae,0.276912259,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Methylophilaceae
Argasidae,Oxalobacteraceae,0.460508445,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Oxalobacteraceae
Argasidae,Rhodocyclaceae,0.764558003,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Rhodocyclaceae
Argasidae,Sphingomonadaceae,0.70198002,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Sphingomonadaceae
Argasidae,Zoogloeaceae,0.034648156,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Zoogloeaceae
Argasidae,Agaricaceae,0.190482976,undirected,A_Argasidae,F_Agaricaceae
Argasidae,Bulleribasidiaceae,0.841600859,undirected,A_Argasidae,F_Bulleribasidiaceae
Argasidae,Camptobasidiaceae,0.841600859,undirected,A_Argasidae,F_Camptobasidiaceae
Argasidae,Chrysozymaceae,0.190482976,undirected,A_Argasidae,F_Chrysozymaceae
Argasidae,Cryptococcaceae,0.055650172,undirected,A_Argasidae,F_Cryptococcaceae

$ cat id_file.csv
Id,Family
1,Argasidae
2,Buthidae
3,Alcaligenaceae
4,Burkholderiaceae
5,Methylophilaceae
6,Oxalobacteraceae
7,Rhodocyclaceae
8,Oppiidae
9,Sphingomonadaceae
10,Zoogloeaceae
11,Agaricaceae
12,Bulleribasidiaceae
13,Camptobasidiaceae
14,Chrysozymaceae
15,Cryptococcaceae
```

I basically want the edge_file.csv output to turn into the output below, where Source and Target have changed from family names to ids instead.

```
Source,Target,Weight,Type,From,To
1,3,0.040968439,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Alcaligenaceae
1,4,0.796351574,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Burkholderiaceae
1,5,0.276912259,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Methylophilaceae
1,6,0.460508445,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Oxalobacteraceae
1,7,0.764558003,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Rhodocyclaceae
1,9,0.70198002,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Sphingomonadaceae
1,10,0.034648156,undirected,A_Argasidae,B_Zoogloeaceae
1,11,0.190482976,undirected,A_Argasidae,F_Agaricaceae
1,12,0.841600859,undirected,A_Argasidae,F_Bulleribasidiaceae
1,13,0.841600859,undirected,A_Argasidae,F_Camptobasidiaceae
1,14,0.190482976,undirected,A_Argasidae,F_Chrysozymaceae
1,15,0.055650172,undirected,A_Argasidae,F_Cryptococcaceae
```

I haven't been able to figure it out with awk since I'm new to it, but I tried some variations from other examples here such as (just testing it out for the "Source" column):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}{$1=a[$1];}1' edge_file.csv id_file.csv
```

Everything just prints out blank. My understanding is that I should create an array for the Source and Target columns in the edge_file.csv, and then replace it with the first column from the id_file.csv, which is the Id column. Can't get the syntax to work even for just one column.

Comment: Really **THINK** about what each statement in your code does. What does `a[$1]=$1` do? It sets `a[foo]=foo`. Given that, what does `$1=a[$1]` do when `$1` is `foo`? Well, we know from the first step that `a[foo]` is `foo` so when $1 is foo, $1=a[foo] is equivalent to $1=foo but $1 is already foo so it changes nothing. Now - think about what you WANTED to do instead...

Comment: what should happen if a `Source` or `Target` string does not exist in `id_file.csv`? or are you 100% sure this can't happen?

Comment: It should not happen because both files are first generated together from an R script, and then manipulated later in proper format. The example I gave above is just a snippet but all the ids and source/target exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. This oneliner should help:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=',' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{$1=a[$1];$2=a[$2]}1' id_file.csv edge_file.csv
```

Comment: Oh yea that worked. Still not quite understanding the syntax. I'll have to go through it slowly.